# Query UITableView for selected cells in order to display "Delete" button

Tags: objective-c, ios, tableview, uibarbuttonitem

Background:

I have a UITableView that displays data from an array. I am utilizing KVO to display an "Edit" button in the navigation bar when the array count is greater than 0 and removes itself when the count is 0. This is working fine. When editing, I place a "Delete" bar button item as the right bar button item. This is also working fine. The Delete button as expected is enabled by default. The table view has multipleSelectionDuringEditing set to YES. I am able to select multiple items and delete them properly. My goal is to enter editing with the Delete button disabled until at least 1 item is selected and subsequently disabled when there are 0 selections. I have tried some things but they have been fruitless. I attempted to have an NSMutableSet property (private) that I could monitor with regards to it's count and appropriately enable/disable the Delete button. However, I have run up against a wall. tableView:DidSelectRowAtIndexPath: is only called on an initial selection during editing, NOT when the row is deselected. Am I overlooking the ability to monitor table selection during editing mode? Thanks in advance.

Additonally, if I were to move the "Delete" button to a UIToolbar with the intention of also including a "Delete All" button, is there a way to select all of the rows (even those not visible)?

Comment: You mention that tableView:DidSelectRowAtIndexPath: is not called when a row is deselected.  This is correct, but tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: IS called, so you can update your variable there.

Comment: Yea, I mentioned below that I completely overlooked that method. Tired eyes I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, calling `-indexPathsForSelectedRows` on the table view can tell you how many are selected right now, and your delegate's `-tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` should be invoked whenever the user deselects a row.

I don't see a convenient method for programmatically selecting multiple rows. If you're doing a "delete all" command, it might be more appropriate to just delete your underlying model objects and then tell the table to update (that is, not worry about selecting them all first). You can animate that using `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and/or `-deleteSections:withRowAnimation:`; either way you'll have to enumerate for yourself which rows/sections you want to delete, but the correspondence between table sections/rows and your collection(s) of model objects should be pretty straightforward, especially since you're nuking everything.

Comment: Thanks! Completely overlooked the -tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: I'm pretty sure this is what I need to manage the selections before deleting. With regards to selecting multiple rows, I guess I didn't quite pay attention to how Messages.app does it. The rows are not all selected on a "Clear all". An Action sheet is presented then they are wiped.